# Why is my question being closed?

Tags: support, closed-questions

The following question was closed as off-topic
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17172243/best-way-to-run-mvc-model-methods

I do not understand why, so as per the instructions here https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions I am posting to understand why.

The original question was closed but specific reasons were not given other than off-topic.  Therefore, I had no constructive criticism.  I edited my post (please view the edits) in order to bring it back on topic and flagged it for moderator attention.

**Why was it closed specifically in the first place? Is it now on topic? If not, how can I improve my question?**

EDIT:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17172243/best-way-to-run-mvc-model-methods has been deleted by myself after understanding why it is off-topic.  For the explanation of what it was off-topic, please see my selected best answer below.

Comment: That looks like a decent question. The [original version](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/75114d19-1af4-497e-9116-b1ffbd111798/view-source) went a bit too far with the background information, but I think it's ok now you've cleaned it up.

Comment: I think it was probably closed because it is a working piece of code. SO is generally for fixing problems, not for improving things. For working code that you'd like to improve, I hear that http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is the right place to post (I have no experience there, so don't take my word for that -- check the faq there and look at other questions there; maybe a code review regular can say something with more clarity). Though personally I don't think I would have closed that question, I can understand why it was.

Comment: And Kudos to being civil and calm about it and posting here to help determine site guidelines. You clearly put a lot of effort into that question, and not everyone would have reacted as well as you did to it being closed.

Comment: Thanks Ben Lee.  I appreciate that.  It can be frustrating when one's question is closed and one does not know why, but I thought it best to really try to understand the guidelines of the site, as you said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This all boils down to your actual question:

> How can I do this in a less coupled manner? Rather than having the methods being called here, is there a better way to do this?

From what I can tell reading through the question, you don't actually have any problem. Your code works, and based on your question, you want it to work *better*.

It looks more like a code review, which isn't on-topic for Stack Overflow. You may rather be interested in [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Also, you should consider re-figuring your title. Including the phrase "best way" is a big red flag for opinion-based questions.

Comment: Thank you very much.  This is very helpful.  I will be posting questions such as this on Code Review..

Comment: Why isn't decoupling your code an actual, practical problem? There's one thing to avoid primarily opinion based questions, and quite another to turn SO to strictly a debugging service.

Comment: @Yannis let's assume I show him a way to decouple his code, and I use Spring.NET for DI, and then I get flamed for using Spring, and then someone else uses Ninject in their answer, and they get flamed, and then another answer says to just not worry because it doesn't matter, and someone else rewrites his entire code in functional style (you wanted less coupling) and someone else answers... I think you get where I'm going with this: we could have dozens of different answers that are all correct (or incorrect, depending on how you feel about Spring). Stack Overflow doesn't do that well.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker [That sounds horrible...](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest) ;) On a more serious note, the question could certainly use a couple more parameters, to better define what "best" means, but it wasn't typical flamebait and I'm not sure we couldn't make it work on SO. I'm ok with it going to Code Review, but the abrupt closure and the lack of comments wasn't ideal.